# How to find how many words there are in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Alright so I need an output where it tells me how many times the same word has occurred. Is there a code or function I could use? I am using Grok Learning for this. This is exactly what I need:I'm trying to figure out this code. I would need the most simplified code, for this. This is what my task is:

---

> You are watching cars go past you while you wait to cross the road and
>   want to see whether red or blue is a more popular colour for cars.
>
> Write a program that reads in a string of the colour of each car that
>   drives past, and then prints out the number of red cars and the number
>   of blue cars.
>
> ```
> Cars: silver red white white blue white black green yellow silver white
> red: 1 blue: 1
> Cars: blue green white black silver silver silver blue silver black silver white white silver white white yellow red red silver red
> red: 3 blue: 2 
> Cars: yellow green white silver white blue white silver yellow pink
> red: 0 blue: 1
> ```

---

---

My current code is:

```
    colours = []
    cars = input("Cars: ")
    colours.append(cars)
    if "red" in cars:
        for colour in colours:
          print("red:",(len(colours)))
    if "blue" in cars: 
        print("blue:",(len(colours)))
```

It outputs incorrect amounts of the word 'red' or 'blue'
Please Help :)

Comment: `Is there a code or function I could use?` <- yes, yes there is

Comment: Well what is it, because after researching I didn't find anything.. @inspectorG4dget

Comment: my attempt is there @AhsanulHaque

Comment: You still haven't shown us what's wrong with your attempt - what the expected behavior was, and how the observed behavior differs from it

Comment: I'm sorry I had accidentally put the incorrect task, I have now updated it. Please take a look and see if you could help me with this :) @inspectorG4dget

Comment: The code that you have posted is not syntactically valid. Please post the exact code that you're using

Comment: see update.... @inspectorG4dget

Comment: Is seems that you completely do not understand what your code does. Why do you use `len()`? Where do you count the number of colours?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import collections

colorCounts = collections.defaultdict(int, collections.Counter(input("cars: ").lower().split()))
needed = 'red blue'.split()
for n in needed:
    print("{}:".format(n), colorCounts[n])
```

Comment: Thank You SOOOO much! I was stuck on this for days. This really helped me. But could you please tell me what the import does?

Comment: Without the `import`, you won't be able to use `collections.Counter`, etc

Comment: if it is okay, would you be able to explain the whole code?

Comment: You mentioned in your initial question that you were using Grok Learning. I can't speak to that site's quality, but it might be worth looking at something like Codecademy's Python course (https://www.codecademy.com/en/tracks/python) if you're trying to solve coding tasks, but still are confused by fundamentals like 'import' in Python. There's a foundation of fundamentals that would make what you're trying to do *much* easier. I hope that doesn't come off as snooty, but it seems a little cart before the horse at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

**Algo**

1. Define days list
2. Get rain days from the user
3. Use set operation to get difference between set 1 from the set 2
4. Display count of day without rain.

**Demo**:

```
>>> day = ['monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday', 'sunday']
>>> rain_days = raw_input("Which days had rain (use space for saparated)? ")
Which days had rain (use space for saparated)? wednesday friday
>>> day_count_without_rain = set(day).difference(days).__len__()
>>> print day_count_without_rain
5
>>>
```

**Note**:
Use `raw_input` in **Python 2.x**

Use `input` in **Python 3.x**

[**Edit 2**]

**By using list and  its count method**

**Demo**:

```
>>> car_colors = raw_input("Enter string of the colour of each car that drives past")
Enter string of the colour of each car that drives past red  blue Red white  black green
# Convert to lower case.
>>> car_colors = car_colors.lower()
#- spit colors in to list.
>>> car_colors = car_colors.split()
>>> print "Red Color cars count:", car_colors.count("red")
Red Color cars count: 2
>>> print "Blue Color cars count:", car_colors.count("blue")
Blue Color cars count: 1
>>>
```

**count** : this will return integer number which is How many times search element present in the string or list .

**Demo**:

```
>>> l = [1,2,3,1, 0]
>>> l.count(1)
2
>>> l.count(11)
0
>>> a = "aagghhttee"
>>> a.count("a")
2
>>> a.count("aa")
1
>>> a.count("aaa")
0
>>>
```

Comment: thank you for your help, but if i'm not bothering you could you please use the coding for python 3. Although I have made some changes. But it is still not working?

Comment: why `.__len__()` ? Why not the [`len`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#len) builtin function?

Comment: @AnandSKumar: yes, but this is faster in performance? `len()` to `.__len__()`

Comment: Thank you so much. This also helped me a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the simplest solution that is also the sample solution provided by Grok Learning:

```
cars = input('Cars: ')
cars = cars.split()

red = blue = 0
for car in cars:
  if car == 'red':
    red += 1
  elif car == 'blue':
    blue += 1

print('red:', red)
print('blue:', blue)
```

I hope this helps!